# Django tutorial unicode not working

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the following in my models.py

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

but when I enter

```
from polls.models import Poll, Choice
Poll.objects.all()
```

I don't get 
Poll: What's up?
but
Poll: Poll object

Any ideas?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Django 1.5 has experimental support for Python 3, but the [Django 1.5 tutorial](http://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.x/intro/tutorial01.html) is written for Python 2.X:

> This tutorial is written for Django 1.5 and Python 2.x. If the Django version doesn’t match, you can refer to the tutorial for your version of Django or update Django to the newest version. If you are using Python 3.x, be aware that your code may need to differ from what is in the tutorial and you should continue using the tutorial only if you know what you are doing with Python 3.x.

In Python 3, you should define a `__str__` method instead of a `__unicode__` method. There is a decorator `python_2_unicode_compatible` which helps you to write code which works in Python 2 and 3.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

For more information see the *str and unicode methods* section in the [Porting to Python 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods) docs.

Comment: I went back a redid all the white space with 4 spaces for each tab resaved, restarted the shell to no avail.  Still not working

Comment: Does it matter what version of python I'm using?  I've got 3.2.3

Comment: Yes, that explains it. It's because you're using Python 3. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Alasdair , Having same error on Python 2.7.5 with Django 1.5.1

Comment: @Zubair Please ask a new question, I can't help you in the comments

Comment: @Alasdair, Thanks I just got it working :) It was an indentation error :(