# Why doesn't the __unicode__ return value show up in Django admin?

Tags: python, django

I made something like this :

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
class SignUp(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    second_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    casPridania=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    casAktualizacie=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_text(self.first_name)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import SignUp
class prihlasenieAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model=SignUp

admin.site.register(SignUp,prihlasenieAdmin)
```

It looks fine, but when I log on my page with /admin and make a new sign up, it doesn't return first name, it returns "Sign up object". I tried to return email and now first_name, but nothing worked.

***//Solved by using __str__ instead of __unicode__ in module.py***

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? If Python 3 then it might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121815/django-tutorial-unicode-not-working.

Comment: curious; why __str__ for Python 3, and __unicode__ for Python 2.7?

Comment: @warath-coder I think this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18034409/870769) is a wonderful write-up that despite being short helps a lot in understanding Python's string-mysterium. So, basically, in Python 3, ``str`` is what used to be ``unicode`` in Python 2.

Answer (score 3):

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name
```