# Django admin form, field instead of object in foreign key

Tags: python, django

Im using a forigen key to reference another object from my parent object. However when i go to the drop down list created by django admin, i get the object name instead of the field value. how can i add the field value to the form instead?

[image: object instead of field name]

admin.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Maintenance
from .models import MaintenanceType
from .models import ServiceType

# Register your models here.


class MaintenanceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Title','Impact','Service','Description','StartTime','EndTime',)
    list_editable = ('Title','Impact','Service','Description','StartTime','EndTime',)


admin.site.register(Maintenance, MaintenanceAdmin)

class MaintenanceTypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Type',)
    list_editable = ('Type',)

admin.site.register(MaintenanceType, MaintenanceTypeAdmin)

class ServiceTypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Service','Service',)
    list_editable = ('Service','Service',)

admin.site.register(ServiceType, ServiceTypeAdmin)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class MaintenanceType(models.Model):
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
                verbose_name = "Planned Maintenance Types"
                verbose_name_plural = "Planned Maintenance Types"

class ServiceType(models.Model):
    Service = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
                verbose_name = "Service Types"
                verbose_name_plural = "Service Types"                

class Maintenance(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Impact = models.ForeignKey(MaintenanceType)
    Service = models.ForeignKey(ServiceType)
    Description = models.TextField()
    StartTime = models.DateTimeField()
    EndTime = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
                verbose_name = "Planned IT Maintenance"
                verbose_name_plural = "Planned IT Maintenance"
```

Answer (score 5):

Implement `__str__` in the `MaintenanceType` model, which should return a string in whatever formatting you wish to appear in the drop down (and anywhere else actually).

It appears that you simply need to `return self.Type`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2 only

You can specify what's returned by accessing an object by setting the **unicode** method to retun what you want it to be.

So I think your `MaintenanceType` should look like

```
class MaintenanceType(models.Model):
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
                verbose_name = "Planned Maintenance Types"
                verbose_name_plural = "Planned Maintenance Types"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Type
```

Comment: This is only relevant to Python2

Comment: For Python3 use `def __str__(self):` instead. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16121911/1167012) for backwards compatibility.